# Alter XPath to Extract Text Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

This HTML block:

```
<td class="tl-cell tl-popularity" data-tooltip="9,043,725 plays" data-tooltip-instant="">
  <div class="pop-meter">
  <div class="pop-meter-background"></div>
  <div class="pop-meter-overlay" style="width: 57%"></div>
  </div>
</td>
```

equates to this XPath:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="album-tracks"]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[6]'
```

Trying to extract the text: 9,043,725 plays with

```
find_element_by_xpath(xpath).text()
```

returns an empty string. This text is only generated when a user hovers their mouse over the HTML block.

Is there a way to alter the XPath so that an empty string is not returned but the actual string is returned?

Comment: This isn't XPath's job when using it with Selenium, use Selenium to get the attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [get_attribute](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_attribute#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) instead. The intended element can be located using any find_elements mechanisms. See the [API DOC](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html)

```
element = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.tl-cell.tl-popularity')
text = element.get_attribute('data-tooltip')
```